# Calling a job from another job in Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

Hey Azure Devops experts,

Do you have any advise how can we call a job from another job in Azure Devops pipeline?
I have already explored and spent time in resources pipeline, however with this another pipeline gets triggered after the completion of first pipeline.

What i want to do is from one job task i may call another job with certain parameters in a loop. So first job will have a loop which will call another job

Comment: One possibility is to call the Azure Devops API, to trigger a different pipeline. It's not easy to code, but it might offer the flexibility you want.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible.

When the pipeline is compiled, this works out all the stages and jobs to be run, and that structure is then fixed for the run; by the time your pipeline is running, it's not possible to add extra jobs.